# remove return breaks from a paragraph

Tags: php, string

```
$lesujet = "testing ...";
$letexts = "a bunch of text   

there is a return break here

another return break as you see";

mail("myemail@gmail.com",$lesujet,$letexts,$headers);
```

I would like to be able to remove the return breaks and keep only 1, I tried :

```
 $letexts = str_replace("\r","",$letexts);
 $letexts = str_replace("\n","",$letexts);
```

it doesnt work.
I am expecting it to output the text formatted like you see above, instead this is what it returns (each return break is doubled which is very annoying ):

```
    a bunch of text   


    there is a return break here


    another return break as you see
```

Comment: Generally it's helpful to give more info when something "doesn't work." What output did you expect to get? What output did you get instead?

Comment: sorry Michael,info added

Comment: No problem :) Sometimes people will downvote questions when they think the poster hasn't described the problem very well. That may be the case here, but your edits have clarified things significantly.

Answer (score 1):

use trim function  [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)  like  this:

```
$letexts = trim($letexts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$letexts = preg_replace("/\r\n\s*\r\n/", "\r\n", $letexts);
```

Comment: didnt work, its so odd that none of them works, I am familiar with str replace and that should ve worked. anyway to display the \n and \r that $letexts contain?

Answer (score 1):

`$letexts = preg_replace('~[\r\n]~','',$letexts)`